# Behaviour of counters

Tags: environments, counters

I'd like to have a numbered list of marginal query-markers. My attempt (below) correctly gives marginal marks ???1 and ???2, but the increment within the itemize environment seems to get lost, and the next query is also tagged ???2.

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcount\countahhqqq
\countahhqqq=0
\def\QQ{ \advance \countahhqqq by 1 \marginpar{\bf ???\number\countahhqqq}}
\begin{document}
Here I raise a question\QQ and get a numbered marginal note.
Now in an itemize environment
\begin{itemize}
\item I'm happy here
\item but less so here\QQ
\end{itemize}
which leaves me wondering what's gone wrong.\QQ
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The change in counter values is local to the scope, so resets after `itemize`. The workaround is to precede your counter advancement with `\global`:

```
\global\advance \countahhqqq by 1
```

This is what LaTeX does naturally when defining and stepping counters via `\newcounter` and `\stepcounter`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\newcount\countahhqqq
%\countahhqqq=0
%\def\QQ{\global\advance \countahhqqq by 1 \marginpar{\bf ???\number\countahhqqq}}

\newcounter{countahhhqqq}
\newcommand{\QQ}{\stepcounter{countahhhqqq}\marginpar{\bfseries ???\thecountahhhqqq}}

\begin{document}

Here I raise a question\QQ{} and get a numbered marginal note.
Now in an itemize environment
\begin{itemize}
  \item I'm happy here
  \item but less so here\QQ
\end{itemize}
which leaves me wondering what's gone wrong.\QQ

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I thought it had something to do with global, but I'd misunderstood the concept and  thought I needed to make the symbol a global symbol.